# How could I use p to replace console.log?

Tags: javascript, console

Here is what we would use normally in javascript

```
console.log('Printing strings in Javascript');
console.log('means using console.log()');
console.log('which seems very boiler platey');
console.log('How could I do something simpler');
console.log('like "p" in Ruby, i.e.');
```

like

```
p('this sort of approach');
p('which seems cleaner?');
p('kinda like an alias')
p('but able to deal with multiple params of different types, functions, etc.');
```

Comment: Just `const p = console.log`?

Comment: i posted that as an answer almost to the second in time with your comment !

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
$ cat main.js

function FirstNames(friends) {
    for (let friend of friends) {
        p(friend);
    }
    return friends;
}

let p = function (...params) { return console.log.apply(console, params); };

p("stringy");
p("stringy", "2nd");
p("stringy", 2);
p("a", [1, 2]);
p(FirstNames(['jin', 'mia']));

$ node main.js 
stringy
stringy 2nd
stringy 2
a [ 1, 2 ]
jin
mia
[ 'jin', 'mia' ]
```

Comment: I'm keen to see other approaches.  It's likely there are better ways and edge cases not covered

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper function called `p`:

```
const p = console.log.bind(console);
```

Then `p(a, b, c)` is the same as `console.log(a, b, c)`.

Live Example:

```js
const p = console.log.bind(console);

// Now this:
p({nifty: "object"}, 42, "string");
// Has the same output as this:
console.log({nifty: "object"}, 42, "string");
```

Look in the real console to see that it handles them the same way (interactive object explorer, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Function` with name p and use it like this.

```
function p() {
    console.log(...arguments);
}

p("hi", "bye");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, very simple way would be to use

```
const p = console.log
```

Note the lack of parens - no `()` - this tripped me at first (i had them initially) without them I think a `super` of some sort is passing params perhaps.
This appear to work and produces the same results.  It's short and simple.  Any drawbacks ?

Comment: "*without them I think a `super` of some sort is passing params perhaps*" - no. You just are assigning the function value to a variable. Remember that functions are first-class values in JS.

Comment: The only drawback could be that you are loosing the base of the method reference, but for `console` in particular that doesn't matter because its methods are already bound.